# Oracle change string to decimal

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to convert string to decimals.

So the string value is: 89,333,22.2345

So i want to keep all decimal places and convert it to: 8933322.2345.

I tried the following query:

select to_number(replace(nvl(89,333,22.2345),0),',','') from dual;

This rounds it to  893322. But i want result with all decimals:

If i try running this query:

```
select to_number((replace(nvl(89,333,22.2345),0),',',''),'9999.99') from dual;
```

it throws error.

Comment: No, the query you said you *tried* has several syntax mistakes, so it produces an error, it does not produce a rounded value of your number. Is it really so hard to **copy and paste** a one-line query, instead of making up something that is full of mistakes and telling us you **tried** it? You didn't try that exact query, did you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select to_number('89,333,22.2345','99,999,99.9999') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're passing the number as a parameter. Otherwise why would you use nvl. Then I see the query you need is going to be similar like that

```
select to_number(replace(nvl('89,333,22.2345','0'),',','')) from dual;
```

Things were wrong at your code:

1. since number is a varchar, it has to be placed between apostrophes
2. nvl takes parameters divided by a comma. And there was one closing bracket too much

nvl(89,333,22.2345),0) -> nvl('89,333,22.2345',0)